# SQL Server Migration Assistance created tables with "dbo."

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I ran the SQL Server Migration Assistance to migrate only my backend tables from an Access 2003 database to SQL Server 2008 Express. Now when I connect to SQL Server via ODBC all of my tables are named like "dbo.tablename". All of my existing queries and forms do not use these names. What is the best way to resolve this problem?

Do I need to change the schema name? What SQL statement(s) would I use to take care of this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't need to rename your tables in your queries at all.

Comment: that's what I figured too but I'm using bound forms in Access and linking via ODBC using a DSN so I don't really have control over the names of the linked tables.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have "control over the names of the linked tables"? No, you don't have control over the names of the SQL Server tables, but you have complete control over the names of the linked tables in your Access front end. While the default name when linking will include "dbo" all you have to do is just rename the linked tables to not use that.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's easy to rename the table links unless you have a lot of them. I ended up making a routine to change them from "dbo_tablename" to "tablename".

Answer (score 1):

I did two different things to resolve the problem detailed in the question above. First I created a routine to rename the tables. Later I decided to abandon this and I wrote a different routine (listed below) to handle the linking of my tables when the database starts up.

```
Public Sub subChangeLinkedTableNames()

    Dim dbCurr As DAO.Database
    Dim tdfCurr As DAO.TableDef

    Set dbCurr = CurrentDb()

    For Each tdfCurr In dbCurr.TableDefs
        If Len(tdfCurr.Connect) > 0 Then
            If Left(tdfCurr.Name, 4) = "dbo_" Then
                tdfCurr.Name = Replace(tdfCurr.Name, "dbo_", "")
            End If
        End If
    Next


    Set tdfCurr = Nothing
    Set dbCurr = Nothing

End Sub
```

The above code worked fine but eventually I decided to write a routine to automate relinking the tables every time I open my Access database. This routine iterates through a list of tables to be linked and for each one, it calls this sub. Notice that I'm resolving the table naming problem by specifying what name I want the table to have in the variable/argument called sLocalTableName:

```
Private Sub LinkODBCTable(sSourceTableName As String, sLocalTableName As String, sIndexFields As String, sConString As String)
    Dim dbCurrent As DAO.Database
    Dim tdfCurrent As DAO.TableDef
    Set dbCurrent = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    'Let's not accidentally delete a local table of the same name
    If Len(dbCurrent.TableDefs(sLocalTableName).Connect) > 0 Then
        dbCurrent.TableDefs.Delete sLocalTableName
    End If
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 0
            'Do Nothing
        Case Else
            Err.Clear
        'Case 3011
            'Table does not exist
    End Select

    Set tdfCurrent = dbCurrent.CreateTableDef(sLocalTableName)
    tdfCurrent.Connect = sConString
    tdfCurrent.SourceTableName = sSourceTableName
    dbCurrent.TableDefs.Append tdfCurrent
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Sometimes 3010 occurs here and I don't know why. A compact and repair always seems to fix it.
        MsgBox "Error in LinkODBCTable" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Number & " " & Err.description
        Err.Clear
    End If

    If sIndexFields <> "" Then
        'sIndexFields should be field names, each enclosed in brackets, comma separated
        'Most of the time it will just be one field
        'This is to tell Access which field(s) is the Primary Key
        dbCurrent.Execute "CREATE INDEX __UniqueIndex ON [" & sLocalTableName & "] (" & sIndexFields & ")", dbFailOnError
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            If Err.Number = 3283 Then
                'Primary Key Already Exists
            Else
                MsgBox "Error in LinkODBCTable" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Number & " " & Err.description
            End If
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End If

    Set tdfCurrent = Nothing
    Set dbCurrent = Nothing
End Sub
```